# How to Reset an Existing Trigger's Identity and Description?

Tags: quartz.net

I have a trigger that I'm passing through an editor, so I can update/change various property values before sending it back to the scheduler. Before sending, I need to give it a new Name, Group and Description. I've started out by using `ITrigger.GetTriggerBuilder()` to create a copy, but I'm having trouble getting the value of `IDailyTimeIntervalTrigger.RepeatCount` to persist.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
sDescription = txtDescription.Text
sGroup = oEditor.Trigger.Key.Group
sName = txtName.Text

oNewTrigger = oEditor.Trigger.
  GetTriggerBuilder.
  WithIdentity(sName, sGroup).
  WithDescription(sDescription).
  Build
```

I've also tried including the existing schedule, like so:

```
sDescription = txtDescription.Text
sGroup = oEditor.Trigger.Key.Group
sName = txtName.Text

oNewTrigger = oEditor.Trigger.
  GetTriggerBuilder.
  WithIdentity(sName, sGroup).
  WithDescription(sDescription).
  WithSchedule(oEditor.Trigger.GetScheduleBuilder).
  Build
```

But `RepeatCount` on the new trigger always has its default value of `-1`.

If there's a way to reset the Name, Group and Description of an existing trigger without using `ITrigger.GetTriggerBuilder()` like this I wouldn't mind doing it, but I'm not finding one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still investigating the possibility that this may be a Quartz.NET bug, but in the meantime in case anyone else runs into the same problem here's the code I ended up with:

```
Public Module Quartz
  <Extension>
  Public Function GetSchedule(Trigger As ITrigger) As IScheduleBuilder
    GetSchedule = Trigger.GetScheduleBuilder

    Select Case Trigger.GetType.Name
      Case "CalendarIntervalTriggerImpl"
        With DirectCast(Trigger, ICalendarIntervalTrigger)
          DirectCast(GetSchedule, CalendarIntervalScheduleBuilder).
            PreserveHourOfDayAcrossDaylightSavings(.PreserveHourOfDayAcrossDaylightSavings).
            SkipDayIfHourDoesNotExist(.SkipDayIfHourDoesNotExist).
            InTimeZone(.TimeZone)
        End With

      Case "DailyTimeIntervalTriggerImpl"
        With DirectCast(Trigger, IDailyTimeIntervalTrigger)
          DirectCast(GetSchedule, DailyTimeIntervalScheduleBuilder).
            WithRepeatCount(.RepeatCount).
            InTimeZone(.TimeZone)
        End With

    End Select
  End Function
End Module
```

This covers the internal method calls that're missing in the two subclassed triggers' `GetScheduleBuilder()` calls.

SimpleTrigger doesn't appear to be affected, so including it here shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Confirmed: it's a [bug](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/issues/237). The fix is scheduled for the next release.

Answer (score 0):

OK, got it.

It was an inheritance issue; I was trying to get a base class (`AbstractTrigger` in this case) to assume the values of its subclass. And of course we all know where *that* leads.

That's why the trigger subclass had default values.

My trigger editor accepts all four types of `ITrigger` (`Calendar`, `Cron`, `DailyTimeInterval` and `Simple`) and in my high-level general trigger update method I wasn't performing the necessary narrowing conversions.

So here's what I ended up with: (with the complete code this time, for clarity)

```
Private Sub UpdateTrigger(Editor As TriggerEditor)
  Dim oBuilder As IScheduleBuilder

  Dim _
    oOldTrigger, 
    oNewTrigger As ITrigger

  Dim _
    sDescription,
    sGroup,
    sName As String

  oOldTrigger = Editor.Trigger
  oBuilder = oOldTrigger.GetScheduleBuilder

  sDescription = txtDescription.Text
  sGroup = oOldTrigger.Key.Group
  sName = txtName.Text

  Select Case Editor.TriggerType
    Case TriggerTypes.CalendarInterval
    Case TriggerTypes.Cron
    Case TriggerTypes.DailyTimeInterval
      DirectCast(oBuilder, DailyTimeIntervalScheduleBuilder).
        WithRepeatCount(DirectCast(oOldTrigger, IDailyTimeIntervalTrigger).RepeatCount)

    Case TriggerTypes.Simple
  End Select

  oNewTrigger = oOldTrigger.
    GetTriggerBuilder.
    WithIdentity(sName, sGroup).
    WithDescription(sDescription).
    WithSchedule(oBuilder).
    Build

  Me.Scheduler.RescheduleJob(oOldTrigger.Key, oNewTrigger)
End Sub
```

Now all that's left is to build out the remaining `Select Case` statements for the other trigger types.

Answer (score 0):

Or ... and this is just a theory ... could the above code be a workaround that's only necessary because of a bug in Quartz.NET?

Here's the relevant source:

```
/// <summary>
/// Get a <see cref="IScheduleBuilder" /> that is configured to produce a 
/// schedule identical to this trigger's schedule.
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
/// <see cref="TriggerBuilder"/>
public override IScheduleBuilder GetScheduleBuilder()
{
    DailyTimeIntervalScheduleBuilder cb = DailyTimeIntervalScheduleBuilder.Create()
        .WithInterval(RepeatInterval, RepeatIntervalUnit)
        .OnDaysOfTheWeek(DaysOfWeek)
        .StartingDailyAt(StartTimeOfDay)
        .EndingDailyAt(EndTimeOfDay);

    switch (MisfireInstruction)
    {
        case Quartz.MisfireInstruction.DailyTimeIntervalTrigger.DoNothing:
            cb.WithMisfireHandlingInstructionDoNothing();
            break;
        case Quartz.MisfireInstruction.DailyTimeIntervalTrigger.FireOnceNow:
            cb.WithMisfireHandlingInstructionFireAndProceed();
            break;
    }

    return cb;
}
```

A `DailyTimeIntervalScheduleBuilder.WithRepeatCount()` call is conspicuously absent from this code. I could be mistaken, but I believe that if it were included I wouldn't have to use the narrowing conversions.